# AmChart3 remove one of several legends

Tags: javascript, amcharts

is it possible to remove one legend?

I want to [remove one of several legends](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tiM6.png). like this picture

Is there a way to delete a part of the legend but make the graph still exist?

i tried to function remove_legend but all legend delete so i want to one legend

remove but graph still alive is it possible??

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFTCE.png)

```
<script>
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "type": "serial",
  "theme": "none",
    "legend": {
        "horizontalGap": 10,
        "maxColumns": 1,
        "position": "right",
    "useGraphSettings": true,
    "markerSize": 10
    },
    "dataProvider": [{
        "year": 2003,
        "europe": 2.5,
        "namerica": 2.5,
        "asia": 2.1,
        "lamerica": 0.3,
        "meast": 0.2,
        "africa": 0.1
    }, {
        "year": 2004,
        "europe": 2.6,
        "namerica": 2.7,
        "asia": 2.2,
        "lamerica": 0.3,
        "meast": 0.3,
        "africa": 0.1
    }, {
        "year": 2005,
        "europe": 2.8,
        "namerica": 2.9,
        "asia": 2.4,
        "lamerica": 0.3,
        "meast": 0.3,
        "africa": 0.1
    }],
    "valueAxes": [{
        "stackType": "regular",
        "axisAlpha": 0.5,
        "gridAlpha": 0
    }],
    "graphs": [{
        "balloonText": "<b>[[title]]</b><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>",
        "fillAlphas": 0.8,
        "labelText": "[[value]]",
        "lineAlpha": 0.3,
        "title": "Europe",
        "type": "column",
    "color": "#000000",
        "valueField": "europe"
    }, {
        "balloonText": "<b>[[title]]</b><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>",
        "fillAlphas": 0.8,
        "labelText": "[[value]]",
        "lineAlpha": 0.3,
        "title": "North America",
        "type": "column",
    "color": "#000000",
        "valueField": "namerica"
    }, {
        "balloonText": "<b>[[title]]</b><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>",
        "fillAlphas": 0.8,
        "labelText": "[[value]]",
        "lineAlpha": 0.3,
        "title": "Asia-Pacific",
        "type": "column",
    "color": "#000000",
        "valueField": "asia"
    }, {
        "balloonText": "<b>[[title]]</b><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>",
        "fillAlphas": 0.8,
        "labelText": "[[value]]",
        "lineAlpha": 0.3,
        "title": "Latin America",
        "type": "column",
    "color": "#000000",
        "valueField": "lamerica"
    }, {
        "balloonText": "<b>[[title]]</b><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>",
        "fillAlphas": 0.8,
        "labelText": "[[value]]",
        "lineAlpha": 0.3,
        "title": "Middle-East",
        "type": "column",
    "color": "#000000",
        "valueField": "meast"
    }, {
        "balloonText": "<b>[[title]]</b><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>",
        "fillAlphas": 0.8,
        "labelText": "[[value]]",
        "lineAlpha": 0.3,
        "title": "Africa",
        "type": "column",
    "color": "#000000",
        "valueField": "africa"
    }],
    "rotate": true,
    "categoryField": "year",
    "categoryAxis": {
        "gridPosition": "start",
        "axisAlpha": 0,
        "gridAlpha": 0,
        "position": "left"
    },
    "export": {
        "enabled": true
     }
});
</script>
```

Comment: can you show all the things you tried?

Comment: have your tried adding `"hiddenInLegend": true`?